# JSR 177 Support on Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, mobile-phones, sim-card, apdu

I have been trying to interact with SIM application through APDU exchanges. For exchanging APDUs, I had to create an APDUConnection through Connector.open() API, but this particular API throws up an IO exception stating "JSR 177 is not supported on this platform", I dont know whether this happens because I test this on simulator or whether it's not supported on Blackberry devices as well.

I would like to know, has anyone been successful interacting with SIM apps on Blackberry? If yes, what's the way to do it? Is it possible to add extensions to the Blackberry SDK, in case if I could implement JSR 177? How do I extend the SDK to include such extensions? I really appreciate any inputs from you folks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JSR 177 is mostly commonly used for communicating with Secure Elements and UICC. JSR 177 will not work on the BlackBerry simulator because it does not support simulating the required hardware. If you want to add NFC simulation, you will need to edit the simulator and follow instructions provided [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/32090/Testing_NFC_applications_1627604_11.jsp). I have not completed these instructions so I do not know if it is possible to simulate a JSR 177 connection to a SIM. From the instructions provided within the link it states,  "The BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator simulates only insecure passive communication."

I advise you read [BlackBerry NFC Primer](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/NFC-Primer-for-Developers/ta-p/1334857) and have some knowledge of interacting Smart Card applications.

It is possible to use JSR 177 on a BlackBerry device however in order to do so you must sign your application with the NCFR or RESE Signatures to be able to access the API. This signature can only be obtained by an application to BlackBerry. You may require both or one of the signatures based upon the APIs you use within your application, however if you want to communicate with the SIM I believe you will only need the NFCR signature.

Below is an short (untested) example of how to create a JSR 177 connection:

```
//The BNF URI is explained within JSR 177, it will connect to the AID specified in the
//target. In this example the AID is the first thing that came to my head and should be an
//application install on the UICC.
    final String BNF_URI = "apdu:0;target=A0.00.00.00.01.02.03.04";

    ...

    //Cmd APDU defines the APDU to be sent to the application on the UICC
    byte[] cmdApdu = new byte[]{ 0x00, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00};
    ApduConnection conn = (ApduConnection)Connector.open();
    byte[] rApdu = conn.exchangeAPDU(cmdApdu);
    ...
```

In the example the R-APDU received will be a byte array of data sent from the application within smart card enviroment.